# How do I load an image in android

Tags: android, json, imageview

How do I load an image from my database to my android application and put it in a listview. The database is MySQL and the image is stored in png format

Here is my codes for retrieving data in my database. The a_emblem is the imageview and the image in my json file

```
private void showResult() {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY1);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String a_shortcut = jo.getString(Config.TAG_a_shortcut);
                String a_emblem = jo.getString(Config.TAG_a_emblem);
                String gold = jo.getString(Config.TAG_gold);
                String silver = jo.getString(Config.TAG_silver);
                String bronze = jo.getString(Config.TAG_bronze);
                String total = jo.getString(Config.TAG_total);
                HashMap<String, String> match = new HashMap<>();
                match.put(Config.TAG_a_shortcut, a_shortcut);
                match.put(Config.TAG_a_emblem, a_emblem);
                match.put(Config.TAG_gold, gold);
                match.put(Config.TAG_silver, silver);
                match.put(Config.TAG_bronze, bronze);
                match.put(Config.TAG_total, total);
                list.add(match);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.standlayout,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_a_shortcut, Config.TAG_a_emblem, Config.TAG_gold, Config.TAG_silver, Config.TAG_bronze, Config.TAG_total},
                new int[]{R.id.shortcut, R.id.img, R.id.gold, R.id.silver, R.id.bronze, R.id.total});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[image: How the Image are stored in my database]

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without more context. How are these images stored in your database? What is the database anyway?

Comment: You should use a custom Adapter class to do that.

Comment: @KenY-N added the database and how the images are stored

Comment: @orange is your images are stored in the form of url?

Comment: @VishvaDave added the table where the images are stored

Comment: you need to upload this images to your server. and store url of this image in table. if you are using local server then can use url : your_ip/folder_name/your_image_name

Comment: then only you can load this urls

Comment: @VishvaDave oh I already did that sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

1. Convert your image to a bitmap.
2. Convert your image to a base64 string and save this base64 string in the database.
3. Convert the base64 string back to the image while using it in the adapter.
4. Set bitmap in ImageView.

It should definitely work. Code for reference

1. Convert drawable to Bitmap

   ```
   Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                      R.drawable.icon_resource);
   ```
2. Use the following method to convert a bitmap to a byte array:

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
   byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
   ```

   to encode a base64 string from a byte array:

   ```
   String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
   ```

   save `encoded` in the database.
3. Convert the base64 string back to `Bitmap`:

   ```
   byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encoded , Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
   ```
4. Set the bitmap to the image view:

   ```
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use Picasso or glide here is the url for you

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
or
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)